# How should we handle people giving answers that are clearly just opinions?

Tags: discussion, answers

It started with a reasonable question, e.g. given that lambdas were added to Java 8, what is the remaining feature gap between Java and Scala?  Some answers were quite good, but one guy who apparently doesn't know or like Scala very much decided to "answer" the question in part by declaring some Scala features to be misfeatures that should be avoided.  It was like a blog entry "What I Think of Scala After Four Months of Use."

I was absolutely horrified at this -- it is certainly *not* what I expect to find on StackOverflow, and if it were very common I would not use StackOverflow at all.  I want facts; tell me what you actually know, but don't present your judgments -- particularly about things you don't understand -- as facts.

I wasn't the only one calling the author to task for that answer.  But what made the situation worse is that this non-factual rant about his opinion of Scala managed to get a significant number of up-votes, probably from Java and Groovy programmers who haven't taken a shine to Scala.  They are welcome to their opinions as well, but again, that kind of crap belongs on a blog and not on StackOverflow.

Right?  I hope?

I handled it poorly, making a point of saying that I had never down-voted an answer before but I would this one because it reeked of personal bias. The author claimed that of course his answer was his opinion, that that was how StackOverflow worked -- we're all just giving our opinions.  What???  I tried editing the most egregious instances of personal bias to say "in my opinion" so that at least someone actually using the page to decide whether or not to invest in Scala would have fair warning, but the author would not have it -- he backed out the edit and responded with hostility.

At that point I gave up, and eventually the question itself was closed as inviting biased answers.  I think that's unfortunate -- the question is really a very good one, and important for people trying to choose which languages to invest in.  It was just that this one guy couldn't resist the chance to blog his opinion.  But my question is: How should I have handled this?  Is there a way to flag an *answer* -- not a question -- for review and potential removal?  Does a crappy answer really have to break the question?

For reference, the question/answer I'm talking about are

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19106382/464309

Comment: `what is the remaining feature gap between Java and Scala?`  That question is *way* too broad for SO.  It's certainly not an appropriate question for this site.

Comment: I think situations like this are why the "Primarily Opinion-Based" Off-Topic reason exists.

Comment: `the question is [...] important for people trying to choose which languages to invest in.`  That's not really something SO is well suited for at all.  It's just not the place to try to figure out which language you should be learning.  You appear to now have quite a bit of hands on experience as to why that is the case and why we work so hard to keep, "which language should I learn" questions off of the site; they don't end well.

Comment: FWIW that "reasonable question" is closed as [meta-tag:opinion-based] and close notice text states "answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions..."

Comment: @gnat He mentioned that in his meta post here. `At that point I gave up, and eventually the question itself was closed as inviting biased answers`

Comment: @Servy; OK, I understand better now why it was closed.  Is there another StackExchange where such a question would be a reasonable fit, or would it be off-topic for all of them?

Comment: @AmigoNico No.  "Which language should I use" questions aren't going to be appropriate anywhere on SE.

Comment: Well, I assume you mean by that "what features does X offer that Y does not?" questions.  OK, thanks.

Comment: @AmigoNico That is not at all what this question is asking.  Listing all of the features a language has *also* doesn't belong on any SE site, but for different reasons.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uiJycy6dFSQ

Comment: @AmigoNico ["We already tried supporting those questions, we even gave them their own site. Sadly, it didn't work out..."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144/165773)

Answer (score 7):

If you feel that an answer is not answering the question that you asked, or that it isn't a useful/helpful answer, you should downvote it.  That's what votes are for.

In general I'd normally follow that up by saying you can optionally comment to say why you feel the answer is problematic, but if the problem is that you think the answerer is being unconstructive in his answer as the reason its not helpful, it's probably best to not engage in further conversation.

---

As to your specific example, it states:

> Given the improvements to Java 8, what are the features in Scala that would still motivate me to adopt Scala as a language?

Note that this is *very* different than your summary here.  It is not asking for a list of differences between the two languages, it's asking, "why would I want to use this language".  That is an *entirely* opinion based question.  Stating what a difference is between two languages is an objective fact (although a list of every single difference is going to be Too Broad); whether that difference is something that would make you want to use the language, or want to not use that language, is purely *opinion*.  The answer is very clearly answering the question that was asked.  The question was asking for opinions, and opinions is what it got.  It even got opinions that you didn't agree with.

Comment: OK, maybe this is just something we have to live with, but part of my point is that this answer managed to accumulate 31 up-votes on top of the several down-votes against it, not because it was a good answer but because other people don't like Scala.  A system that relies on downvotes going negative fails in this case.

Comment: @AmigoNico As I said in comments to your question here, this is really stemming from problems with the question.  A question like this is simply going to attract answers that we don't want here, and not encourage the types of answers that we *do* want here.

Comment: Just to be clear, the question we are talking about was not my question, as I think you are assuming.  I was just reading the answers.  And I understood the question quite clearly to be asking what additional features Scala offers, although it sounds like you read it quite differently -- perhaps because of the word "motivate"?  Interesting.

Comment: @AmigoNico Nothing about the question is asking for a list of all features that Scacla has that Java 8 doesn't.  The question is asking, *given the differences*, why should I choose that language.  This is in effect asking what differences you should care about, which ones "matter".  That's entirely a matter of opinion.

Comment: Servy, I'm afraid we are going to just have to agree to disagree on this one.  The question most certainly does not say "given the differences" -- it quite explicitly *asks* for the differences.  "*What are the features* [that Scala offers but Java still does not]."  I think we are  done, though -- I understand now that the question really was off-topic, even in my interpretation, and that there is no StackOverflow mechanism for dealing with answers which despite being opinion-based manage to garner votes.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AmigoNico It asks for a list of the differences *that would cause someone to use that language*.  It seems like you just stopped reading after the word "Scala".  It doesn't just ask for a list of differences, not even close.  Now, both questions are inappropriate on the SE network; they're inappropriate for wildly different reasons, but still both inappropriate.